# Manually trigger onmove in interact.js

Tags: javascript, jquery, interact.js

I add / delete with jquery onto / from the set of class="draggable" elements i am using with interactjs. When i add some new elements with specific positions, like:

```
<p class="draggable" data-x="100" data-y="100">
```

They don't appear at the correct position, only after i touched them once with the mouse and the corresponding interactjs events got called to update the position.

How can i trigger this manually using jquery, if my list of object looks like this?

```
$(data).each(function() {
    $(this).update() ??
}
```

Thanks!

Comment: I would definitely need a fiddle to play with

Comment: @myfunkyside: Have a look at https://jsfiddle.net/vb100h2n/. There is a workaround with position absolute to enforce it on a certain position. However there must be a normal way to set $(el).css() the x and y coordinate of the element and then update the visual position by just invoking the listeners. How to?

Comment: In your fiddle, have you already applied this workaround? 'Cause I can't find what's not working (keep in mind I don't know this code, and have no experience with interactjs). Could you insert the lines of code in your answer that cause the problem, and then also insert the workaround you have found, so that I (and everyone else) knows exactly where the problem lies. (And please make an update of your fiddle to the original state of your code, with the bug, so we can see where the problem lies.

Answer (score 0):

You have probably already solved this, but as I just had the same issue maybe I'll write my solution here. Adding CSS transforms helped, like so:

```
<p class="draggable" data-x="100" data-y="100" style="transform: translate(100px, 100px); -webkit-transform: translate(100px, 100px);">
```

The element should now appear in the right location.